# inner join in hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql

I am just a beginner in Hibernate, I would like to execute this query but I don't know how .. any help please?

```
SELECT DISTINCT agents.username 
  FROM users u
       INNER JOIN UserDistributors ud 
                  ON u.id = ud.[user]
       INNER JOIN users agents 
                  ON agents.type =9
       INNER JOIN UserDistributors agentsdistributor 
                  ON agentsdistributor.distributor = ud.distributor 
                  AND agents.id=agentsdistributor.[user]
 WHERE u.id=1778
```

my user.hbm file has one to many relation to distributor

```
 <set name="userDistributors" table="UserDistributors" 
      inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
     <key>
         <column name="[user]" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="net.tedata.dp.model.UserDistributors" />
        </set>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(User.class);

c.createAlias("ud", "UserDistributors"); // inner join by default
c.add(Restrictions.eq("ud.id", "<Name>"));
```